# How to add Google Recaptcha to Firefox addons

Tags: firefox, recaptcha, add-on

I'm implementing a browser extension support both Chrome and Firefox and I have to add Google ReCaptcha to login form in popup.

I've added it to Chrome Extension and it's work.
Just add the extension ID (bjcdodbcokocoemaffplobbmbvdhjomn) to Google ReCaptcha Console.

But I cannot add Firefox Add-on ID to Google ReCaptcha Console, they don't accept Firefox UUID (4c9d0fba-15aa-3a46-a9e2-2ef1f486c569).

If you already succeed to integrate Google ReCaptcha to Firefox Add-on, please help me.

Thanks